# Layout for 480*800 screens

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I have problem in Android app.

My layouts don't working correctly on 480*800 screens

On HD, Full HD and qHD it working correctly

[image]

For example my axml code:

http://pastebin.com/a07PB0MV

How can I make it working correctly

Comment: show ne you design xml file

Comment: don't use static height/width because android device have diffrent dpi of each model . show use diman of give value for all DPI using value folder or manage layout using weight property of linear layout

Comment: you talking about match_parent & wrap_content? @DivyeshBoda

Comment: yah you set static height and width insted of match_parent & wrap_content. and you want to set static width or height than use diman for for diffrent screen dpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the Xamarin Android designer and Android Studio(which many use for UI design) have a dropdown for different device layouts. This should help with at least visually looking at the app on lower resolution phones.

You could also use a screen density specific layout, where a specific layout is created for the smaller phone screen sizes(like 480x800).

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

See the section on "Using new size qualifiers"